# SQL - SELECT person_name where locations is a specific city

Tags: sql

I started my uni degree (yiha!) and I'm kinda stuck with this one task. The following tables are given:

[image]

[image]

The task is to pick all person_names, who ate a pizza in Salzburg.

Obviously, `pizzeria_name` is a foreign key (at least if I got it right), but how do I access this? I assume I have to use WITH / AS for that?

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I was able to solve it on my own, thanks to the JOIN recommendations in the comments.

```
SELECT person_name 
FROM ISST 
INNER JOIN PIZZERIA ON PIZZERIA.`id` = ISST.`pizzeria_id` && PIZZERIA.`stadt`="Salzburg"
```

The user @dima_bor posted a very familiar answer, which I first saw after solving it. I will still accept it as the correct answer for trying to help.

Greetings!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
SELECT Isst.person_name
FROM Isst
INNER JOIN Pizzeria ON Isst.pizzeria_name = Pizzeria.pizzeria_name  
WHERE Pizzeria.stadt = "Salzburg";`
```

That should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the Isst table to the Pizzeria on pizzeria_name. Then you do your where clause as usual

Comment: Okay, but how do i compare the city? SELECT person_name FROM Isst INNER JOIN Pizzaria ON (Isst.pizzaria_name = Pizzeria.stadt = "Salzburg") doesn't makes too much sense. How can i access and compare the city from Isst?

Comment: As @xstrafez_ wrote: 1st you join on the FP/PK column and then you search for Salzburg in a WHERE-condition